# Clean Up Caches and Update Paths

Tags: civimail, drupal, cache

Running CiviCRM 4.3.8 on Drupal 7.37 (for now, but we're in the long process of a major upgrade of our website). Often I have to update the paths because they revert to a different docroot which may have been originally set up for testing purposes. (Let's call them A and B, A is the correct one and B is the wrong docroot.)

When it reverts seems to be at random and I cannot find the cause, but it causes problems such as emails going out with links to a test website in B's docroot, the reports will not load, etc.

Update file paths settings will show:

Old Base Directory - 
/var/www/html/B/docroot/sites/default/files/

New Base Directory - 
/var/www/html/A/docroot/sites/default/files/

Edit: The CiviCRM installation is in a separate docroot from the Drupal installation (for now) and uses symlinks in sites/all/modules in order for Drupal to find it.

Comment: That's a very old version of CiviCRM! [Consider upgrading](https://civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=78).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our CiviCRM was installed outside of the Drupal root in order to circumvent performance issues with Drupal commons. I have re-engineered so that CiviCRM is now inside the Drupal root and upgraded. I also noticed multiple instances of Drupal in /var/www/html so I moved all other copies to a backups folder outside of the html folder.

We no longer have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check your civicrm.settings.php file to be sure that the $civicrm_root variable is correctly set, as is all the other settings in that file.  Be sure to check all the way to the end of the file, just in case some override was done.